# Zend Framework - and in where clause

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, where-clause

I am working on Zend Framework, got 1 problem in query, i want to fetch userid from tbl_user & want to check record with And in where clause

```
here is my query
$sql=$this->select()->from(users)->where('email = ? ', trim($email) , 'password = ?', md5(trim($password)) );
```

when i am printing query it prints

```
select * from users where email = 'test@gmail.com';
```

i want to print query like

```
select * from users where email = 'test@gmail.com' AND password='123456';
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close. You just need to call the `where()` method twice:

```
$this->select()->from(users)->where('email = ?', trim($email))
                            ->where('password = ?', md5(trim($password)));
```